# How to encode a set of whole numbers $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ such that given a number $x$ we can test if $x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Suppose we have a set of whole numbers $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$. Is there a way to encode them into a new number $e$ such that we can use $e$ to test if a given number $x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$? So really I'm looking for two things:

1. Encoding function
   $$f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=e$$
2. Test function
   $$p_e(x)=true \iff x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$$

I'm using this in a computer program so the numbers can't get too big, and it would also be very beneficial to be something that can be implemented to run quickly. Thank you all, cheers.

Comment: You mean $x \in \{ a_1,a_2,...,a_n \}$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant I can change it.

Comment: This sounds like a question for a computer coding stack exchange. It doesn't really seem like a math problem. Probably some kind of sort algorithm, and just check $x=a_k$, iterate over $k$.

Comment: I can try out code stack thanks for the suggestion. Also I would like to be able to test $x$ using only the "encoded" number $e$.

Comment: There are many ways of doing it (using prime decompositions or putting binary expansions in a base-ten number are two immediate ways I can think of), but I don't know a good one (i.e. one where the test function isn't basically "decode $e$  back into $\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ and then check")

Comment: Is there a reason you are rejecting the usual CS solutions: binary search through the sorted list of $a_i$ or construct a binary search tree in "step $f$" and then search through that in "step $p$"?  A short combinatorial argument will show that your number $e$ *must* be "as complicated" as the list of $a_i$, so cannot be much better *than* the list of $a_i$.

Comment: The short version is I have millions of records in a database, and each record can have several "tags" used for filtering. I was just curious if there was some way to encode all of the tags into a single value on the record. (So I don;t have to do so many database joins). There are plenty of better ways of optimizing for this. Really I'm just curious if it's possible. (Sometimes people get clever with hashing algorithms).

Comment: What do you mean by "number": real number, rational number, integer, positive integer?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, given all $\{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\}$ are different since you stated it's a set, such a function is possible. 
$$f(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n 2^{a_k}=E$$
In other words, the binary form of $E=(1001...0010...)_2$ has the property that

- at the position $a_k$ we have the digit $1$, for every $k=1..n$ and
- in all the other positions we have the digit $0$.

Now $$x \in \{a_1,a_2,...,a_n\} \Leftrightarrow 2^{x} \text{ & } E =2^x$$
where $\text{&}$ [is the bitwise AND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND).

Comment: I might observe that this $f(\vec{a})$ will be a somewhat large-ish number for $a_i$ that aren't all laughably small...

Comment: True, thus I started my answer with "Theoretically ...". However, Python, C++, Java (e.g. BigInteger) can handle large numbers for scientific purposes, but yes, up to a limit ...